# border-radius wont apply to top of div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a landing page just for personal use, but i have ran into a problem. I have a div with a border radius, its called .popOut. The border radius applies to the bottom of the div but not the header part, why? And how can i fix this? Also if you know how to make the box-shadow a little bit lighter and not as dark that would be great! Thanks!

Code:

HTML:

```css
    *{margin:0; padding:0;}
    body{
     background: #CCC;
     color:#000305;
     font-size: 87.5%;
     font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
     line-height: 1.5;
     text-align: left; 
    }
    .body{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 70%;
     background:#ebebeb;
     margin:auto;
    }
    .mainBack{
     margin:auto;
     background:white;
     width:600px;
     height:650px;
    }
    .popOut{
     background:white;
     width:80%;
     height:600px;
     margin:auto;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px;
     border-radius:6px;
     position:relative;
     top:30px;
    }
    .mainHeader{
     background:linear-gradient(#465BF6,#3149F2);
     width:100%;
     height:100px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>
       Welcome!
      </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
     </head>
     <body class="body">
      <div class="mainBack"> 
       <div class="popOut">
        <div class="mainHeader"></div>
        <div class="mainArea"></div>
        <div class="mainAreaB"></div>
        <div class="mainFooter"></div>
       </div> 
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just copy and paste to a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.mainHeader` div is covering your border-radius of the `.popOut` div. You could add this line to your `.mainHeader` class: `border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;`

Also, to make your box-shadow lighter just add a color like this:

`box-shadow:#777 0px 0px 15px 0px;`

Here's an example:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
 background: #CCC;
 color:#000305;
 font-size: 87.5%;
 font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-align: left; 
}
.body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 background:#ebebeb;
 margin:auto;
}
.mainBack{
 margin:auto;
 background:white;
 width:600px;
 height:650px;
}
.popOut{
 background:white;
 width:80%;
 height:600px;
 margin:auto;
 box-shadow:#777 0px 0px 15px 0px;
 border-radius:6px;
 position:relative;
 top:30px;
}
.mainHeader{
 background:linear-gradient(#465BF6,#3149F2);
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
        border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>
   Welcome!
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body class="body">
  <div class="mainBack"> 
   <div class="popOut">
    <div class="mainHeader"></div>
    <div class="mainArea"></div>
    <div class="mainAreaB"></div>
    <div class="mainFooter"></div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend using `rgba()` for your box-shadow like this: `box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(100,100,100,0.5)` This will allow you to change the color and the opacity (the `a` which is alpha). You could always do both to support browsers that don't support the `rgba` property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that `.mainHeader` does not have a border-radius: and is overflowing over the edge of `.popOut`.
You can fix it by giving main header a border-radius:

```
.mainHeader{
        background:linear-gradient(#465BF6,#3149F2);
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/08fe6225/1/)
or by giving `.popOut` overflow hidden:

```
.popOut{
        background:white;
        width:80%;
        height:600px;
        margin:auto;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px;
        border-radius:6px;
        position:relative;
        top:30px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/08fe6225/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy add, `overflow: hidden;` to `.popOut`

Sorted!

The reason this happened is because your blue div is covering the popOut div, which in turn covers the rounded corners. Adding `overflow:hidden;` hides anything that goes outside your popOut container!

As for box-shadow take a look here: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

I find it very useful even with a lot of experience. You can add rgba to box shadow as shown in the link above, this enables you to change color and opacity!